# WiFi issue on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, wireless, internet

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 as dual boot with windows 11.
During the installation process there was no issue of connecting to the WiFi. After the install and reboot the wifi network is detected and connects but I am unable to access the internet. I can access the internet through the hotspot of my smartphone which is connected to the same WiFi network.
There is no such issue with windows.
Can anyone help me with this?

terminal output:

```
shyam@shyam-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X412FAC-X412FA:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:02f0]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
shyam@shyam-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X412FAC-X412FA:~$
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. Is Windows Fast Startup disabled?

Comment: Output is added to the question. I have disabled fast boot on the BIOS

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Terminal output is text. I asked not about fast boot in the BIOS but Windows Fast startup Feature.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it again. Also the Windows fast startup feature is enabled. Its not disabled.

Comment: Disable Windows Fast Startup. It should fix the issue.

Comment: It didn't work. I have noticed one thing right now that the WiFi works fine when the laptop is very close to the router. But it becomes inaccessible at about 2 meters away from the router. I usually sit about 4 meters away from the router where it works very fine on my windows.